# Push to another viewcontroller is too late

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xib, viewdidload

In my project while i will redirect from "input screen" to "Result screen" too late. I have guess this is due to below reasons.

- I'm using more calculations before pushing in "input screen".
- I'm using more methods and coding in "viewDidLoad" in "Result screen".
- I'm using more designs UI in "Result screen".

Please suggest me "How to optimize?" above mentioned points.

- Do we have any "dispatch_queue" concept to speed up navigation speed?
- Do we have any method in "xib" for "Faster redirect screen to next screen"?
- Do we have any concept to optimize code in "viewDidLoad".

NOTE: iPad is take more time to redirect next screen compare than iPhone.

Comment: Where is your code? You mean the animation is too late?

Comment: yes...animation is too late due to more code. we have more codes so we can't to provide you the code.

Answer (score 0):

Put your calculations in **viewDidLoad** 
and if your new page have any request or any other low priority code then put it into **viewWillAppear**

I just want to say you split your code with  **viewDidLoad** and  **viewWillAppear**.

Hope will effect.
**Note: Not sure because without sample of code we cant say what actually happening with your code**

Comment: Thank you i will try this method and let you know